# Konva - conditionally change rectangle color while dragging

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag

I am developing something similar to a Gantt-Chart using a Konva wrapper for Vue.js. I basically have a group which contains a rectangle (and some other elements which are irrelevant in this case). The group is draggable and I would like to change the fill color of the rectangle if the group overlaps another group while dragging. I have already implemented the logics for putting a flag which says whether the dragged group is overlapping, but I fail at changing the fill color. The mechanism looks like this:

```
  //--- config object for the group: ---
   groupTemplate: { 
          name: "test",
          x: 100,
          y: 100,
          width: 100, 
          height: 20,
          draggable: true,
          dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
            return {
              x: getXPos(pos.x),
              y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y       //prevents vertical dragging
            }
          }
        }
```

The crucial part is the getXPos function. It basically sets a boolean to "true" if we are overlapping:

```
 function getXPos(posx) {
    ...    
    / *** check if we are overlapping, then: *** /
    ...
    if (overlapping)
      myDraggedGroup.rect.fill = "#4b9161"
    else 
      myDraggedGroup.rect.fill = "#f49542"

  }
```

However, this fails to work. The rectangle's color changes only AFTER having dragged the group, not WHILE we are still dragging it. I assume that I have to manually invoke some Konva "redrawing" function, but that's the part where I am stuck. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: where are your drag events listeners ?

Comment: Just found a solution, check my answer. It indeed involved a dragmove event listener. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the meantime by myself. The solution was to add a `@dragmove` event listener to the whole group and obtain the element we wish to modify (in my case it was the rectangle inside the group) using `getStage()`and then `fill()` to change the color.

Template:

```
 <v-group ... @dragmove="onDragmoveGroup($event)" ...>
        <!-- the actual rectangle -->
        <v-rect :config="plan.rect"></v-rect>
         ....
 </v-group>
```

Script:

```
methods: {
      ...
     onDragmoveGroup(self) {
        let rect = self.$children[0].getStage()  // get rectangle
        if (overlapping)
            rect.fill("#FFF")
        else
            rect.fill("#000")
      }
    ...
}
```

This way, the rectangle changes it's fill color WHILE being dragged.